# Nodejs: How to handle http request throttle error using async/await?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, async-await

I m trying to build a search API which takes the location as the argument and returns the latitude and longitude of that location.
I m using  http://geocode.xyz to get the details of the location. 
For example : 
https://geocode.xyz/?locate=Warsaw,Poland&json=1
This will return the required latitude and longitude of that location.

This is the code snippet I have:

```
const url = 'https://geocode.xyz/?locate=Warsaw,Poland&json=1';
const getData = async url => {
try {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const json = await response.json();
  console.log(json);
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
};
getData(url);
```

With this, this is the error I am seeing:

```
node geocode.js
{success: false, error: { code: '006', message: 'Request Throttled.'}}
```

I guess the error is because I need to throttle the number of requests that is hitting the API https://geocode.xyz. I m not sure how to use rate limiter with async/await. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** 
Based on the answers below, I still see 'Request Throttled'

```
var request = require('request');
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

const requester = {
    lastRequest: new Date(),
    makeRequest: async function(url) {
        // first check when last request was made
        var timeSinceLast = (new Date()).getTime() - this.lastRequest.getTime();
        if (timeSinceLast < 2000) {
            this.lastRequest = new Date(this.lastRequest.getTime() + (2000 - timeSinceLast));
            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000-timeSinceLast));
          //  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, timeSinceLast));
        }
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const json = await response.json();
        return json;
    }
};
requester.makeRequest('https://geocode.xyz/?locate=Warsaw,Poland&json=1')
.then(console.log)
```

I m still getting the same error:

```
{ success: false, error: { code: '006', message: 'Request Throttled.' } }
```

Is this because of [geocode pricing](https://geocode.xyz/pricing)? Is there any way to limit the rate of requests from the user side?

Comment: How are you calling this that it gets throttled? In a loop?

Comment: The API website says that the free usage is `(Throttled to no more that 1 request per second for all free port users combined. eg., if 2 free requests come at the same time, each gets throttled to 2 seconds per request)`. In other words, there is no handling except paying for the service.

Comment: @Phix: I am not using a loop. I've this script and I am running it as `node geocode.js` 

@ChrisG: Can I then rate limit to send 1 request per second and handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make an object that is used for sending all requests out, and that object can keep track of when the last time a request was made. For example

```
const requester = {
    lastRequest: new Date(2000,0,1),
    makeRequest: async function (url) {
        // first check when last request was made
        var timeSinceLast = (new Date()).getTime() - this.lastRequest.getTime();
        this.lastRequest = new Date();
        if (timeSinceLast < 1000) {
            this.lastRequest = new Date(this.lastRequest.getTime() + (1000 - timeSinceLast));
            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000-timeSinceLast));
        }

        // make request here and return result
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const json = await response.json();
        return json;
    }
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3k7b0grd/

if you use `requester.request`, it only lets you make a request once a second, and waits long enough (even for successive requests) to obey that rate limit

Comment: How would you use this object though? In the search api?

Comment: `var requestResponse = await requester.makeRequest('url')`

Comment: This is what i tried

```const requester = {
    lastRequest: new Date(),
    makeRequest: async (url) => {
        var timeSinceLast = (new Date()).getTime() - this.lastRequest.getTime();
        if (timeSinceLast < 1000) {
            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, timeSinceLast));
        }
        var requestResponse = await requester.makeRequest('https://geocode.xyz/?locate=Warsaw,Poland&json=1')
        request('https://geocode.xyz/?locate=Warsaw,Poland&json=1', function (error, response, body) {
                  console.log(response)
     });}};```

Comment: after awaiting the settimeout, just do what you did in OP, `const response = await fetch(url);
  const json = await response.json(); return json;`. Then, from anywhere else in your app, you can call `await requester.makeRequest('url')`

Comment: Thanks! Although, I am seeing the error `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function` when I I call it anywhere. Is `await` required?

Comment: Without 'await', I am seeing the error: 

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTime' of undefined
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch().`

Comment: Oh you know what, I kinda messed it up by making `requester.makeRequest` an arrow function. And actually the rest of my code is messed up as well. I'm working on a better one

Comment: What you really need is an async queue which is a bit difficult

Comment: Actually, I think I sorted it out @sum91. check this fidle out: https://jsfiddle.net/3k7b0grd/

Comment: @TKoL : thanks a lot ! but I m still getting the error message which says : ````response { success: false, error: { code: '006', message: 'Request Throttled.' } }```` 

After trying this : 
````async function getData() {
 let response = await requester.makeRequest('https://geocode.xyz/?locate=Warsaw,Poland&json=1');
  console.log('response', response)
  let newSrc = response.message;
}```` 

I think its because of the https://geocode.xyz/pricing
Not sure how to set the limit for these requests hitting the geocode.xyz API.

Comment: If you're still getting throttled, you could try adding more than 1000ms to the delay in my example. try 2000 first